# ¿Como puedo reemplazar index.php por ?view=ejemplo en la barra de direcciones?

Tags: php

Lo que quiero hacer es que cuando se detecte `index.php` en la barra de direcciones se cambie a `?view=hola`.

Answer (score 0):

No hace falta hacer que se cambie, los servidores buscan por defecto los archivos `index`, cuando vayas a hacer un re direccionamiento, la url debe ser así:

**Pasas de esta URL:**

```
www.tupagina.com/ejemplo/index.php?view=ejemplo
```

**A esta URL**

```
www.tupagina.com/ejemplo/?view=ejemplo
```

Comment: Esque va haber personas que pongan por index.php y va a detectar error, por que no hay variables.

Comment: El error se generaria porque el usuario no pondría `?view=ejemplo`?

Comment: si por que cuando aparece ?view=ejemplo se genera ?view=ejemplo&user=13323&comand=osdkakaamskas